# System Emails not working

Tags: 7, emails

I have a website for my business, however, there is an issue.

All the system emails have not been delivered. I have tried with password reset, it shows entry in dblog. Also the server is fine, if I add a custom php file with email sending code, it works absolutely fine.

But with Drupal, its not working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Any chance someone changed the settings in [Account Settings](https://dc4mw.ply.st/node#overlay=admin/config/people/accounts) ?

Comment: Usually, an examination of the SMTP server logs is helpful.

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: SMTP is configured. I tried sending email with a php script, the issue lies in Drupla

Comment: Junk/folder is empty either